# Detect The Last Instance Of A ForEach() Loop Inside A Promise — JavaScript

Tags: javascript, loops, foreach, promise, instance

I have some image files that are previewed as part of a file uploader. A well as validations happening in the backend (PHP) I am setting up frontend validations too.

When the images are attached to the uploader's file `<input>` element, a preview thumbnail is generated using `URL.createObjectURL()`

These previews are looped over and a `decode()` method inside the loop detects if they fail certain criteria. If they fail then an error message is outputted / attached to the specific image file (preview thumbnail) that fails.

If this error message is detected, a generic error message appears at the top of the page telling the user to check the errors shown on the image previews thumbnails.

**The Issue**

The generic error message at the top of the page is outputted, but because this all happens inside a loop, if 5 files are attached, and only one fails, the generic error message flashes because it is being detected on each instance of the loop.

**The Question**

How do I detect the last instance of a loop and only output the generic error message when the last loop instance happens?

**Note:** I have included a simplified example of the code below, but would be happy to show the full code (but I am thinking this might be overkill in relation to the issue).

```
submitData = new DataTransfer();

// initial 'change' event listener on the files input element which is stored in a variable 'attachFiles'
attachFiles.addEventListener("change", (e) => {

    // stuff here handles the data transfer method and detects any change in the number of files attached etc

    // then run the 'showFiles function on each file attached
    [...submitData.files].forEach(showFiles);

});

function showFiles(file) {
    let previewImage = new Image();

    // Set relevant <img> attributes
    previewImage.className = "upload-preview-image";
    previewImage.src = URL.createObjectURL(file);

    // get the original width and height values of the thumbnail using the decode() method
    previewImage.decode().then((response) => {

        let w = previewImage.naturalWidth;
        let h = previewImage.naturalHeight;

        // error message that is appended to each image when it fails
        let resError = `<p class="upload-preview-error">Image must be bigger than 2MP</p>`

        if(w * h < 2000000) {
            // append the above errorMessage to the specific image preview in question
            previewImage.insertAdjacentHTML('beforebegin', resError);
        }

        // store HTML class from the above template string in a variable
        let imgError = document.querySelectorAll('.upload-preview-error');

        // set the variable that changes to true when an error message is detected
        let imgErrorMessage = false;

        /* SOMEHOW RUN THIS NEXT CODE ON THE LAST INSTANCE OF THE LOOP, 
        SO THAT THE MAIN ERROR MESSAGE AT THE TOP OF THE PAGE IS ONLY OUTPUTTED ONCE 
        */

        if(imgError.length) {
            if (imgErrorMessage === false) {

                // Append this generic message into a <div> with the class '.js-upload-error'
                document.querySelector('.js-upload-error').innerHTML = `<p class="warning">YOU HAVE ERRORS. CHECK YOUR IMAGES BELOW</p>`

                imgErrorMessage = true;

            }
        }
    }).catch((encodingError) => {
        // Do something with the error.
    });

} // end of showfiles(file)
```

Comment: forEach callback takes 3 arguments, current item, current index and the array ... so when the current index is array.length - 1 that's the last item

Comment: You don't. You collect the error messages (use `Promise.all` since you're dealing with promises), then *after* the loop you check if there were any (and how many) and then display your message.

Answer (score 2):

You look to have a dummy error handling block here:

```
}).catch((encodingError) => {
    // Do something with the error.
});
```

When there are problems, consider throwing an error inside `showFiles` and then handling it in the caller by using `Promise.allSettled` to wait for all calls to settle (to either fulfill or reject).

From a UI perspective, you almost certainly also want to actually do something to tell the user when there's some other error - in other words, drop the `empty // Do something with the error.` block entirely and let the caller deal with it. (Or, if you actually do do something with the error in that block, you can re-throw it so that the caller's `.allSettled` can see that there was a problem.)

```
function showFiles(file) {
    const previewImage = new Image();
    previewImage.className = "upload-preview-image";
    previewImage.src = URL.createObjectURL(file);
    return previewImage.decode().then((response) => {
        const w = previewImage.naturalWidth;
        const h = previewImage.naturalHeight;
        const resError = `<p class="upload-preview-error">Image must be bigger than 2MP</p>`
        if (w * h < 2000000) {
            previewImage.insertAdjacentHTML('beforebegin', resError);
            throw new Error('Image too small');
        }
    });
}
```

and replace

```
[...submitData.files].forEach(showFiles);
```

with

```
Promise.allSettled([...submitData.files].map(showFiles))
    .then((results) => {
        if (results.some(result => result.status === 'rejected')) {
            document.querySelector('.js-upload-error').innerHTML = `<p class="warning">YOU HAVE ERRORS. CHECK YOUR IMAGES BELOW</p>`;
            // you can put more error handling here
            // or you can put it in the .catch block if you re-throw
        }
    });
```

If there's an error *other* than the image being too small, you might add such an error message in the `.catch`, such as:

```
return previewImage.decode().then((response) => {
    // ...
})
    .catch((error) => {
        if (error.message !== 'Image too small') {
            previewImage.insertAdjacentHTML('beforebegin', '<p class="upload-preview-error">Decoding error</p>');
        }
        throw error;
    });
```

or use the `.then(success, fail)` syntax.